# Permission denied on modify .nuxt folder

Tags: nuxt.js

Command `npm run dev` doesn't regenerate new files (.nuxt folder) correctly.

I can't access new routes created (creating a new page file) from browser even if the new route is present in the router.js file. I need to restart dev server manually to access the new route. Sometimes, when i restart dev server manually, console gives me this error `EPERM: operation not permitted [PATH_TO_.nuxt_COMPONENTS_FOLDER]`. I'm working on Windows 10.

*Edit:* Seems that the integrated webpack has some problem when touching the .nuxt folder. When i  launch `npm run dev` the .nuxt folder is deleted (not always) and then recreated and everything works fine, but when some changes are detected, in the pages folder for example, and webpack tries to touch the right files without deleting the entire .nuxt folder here the `EPERM` error comes into play.

Comment: nuxt version? Did u tried to delete your lock file and node modules and reinstall? there was issue in 2.9.1 similar to this

Comment: Nuxt.js v2.9.2. Deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` doesn't bring any effects. I tried to use an older version of Nuxt.js, v1.X.X, and i have experienced the same effects with a lower rate, sometimes everything works and sometimes not. Also, with v1.X.X some error about discrepancies about what it's rendered on the browser and what the server is serving shows up, but even this error appears with a lower frequency.

Comment: that might be because some of your programs reading generated nuxt folder at that time. E.g. your IDE indexing it while u trying to delete and tus fails to delete, or your antivirus checking files etc

Comment: Well, it's not so annoying, again, it appears with a low frequency, i can live with it. Is there a solution for my permission issue with Nuxt.js v.2.X.X? Is it at least known to the development team?

Comment: its now know because its specific to your setup as i said. Something is holding your files at that moment e.g. antivirus or ide - thats most likely cause.

Comment: Well, let me know if you want more info about my setup to replicate the error. Recently i've encountered another user that has come up with a similar issue as mine on a unix based os (i don't know if he's on Mac or some Linux distro). For now i'll stick with Nuxt.js v1.X.X

Comment: try to disable your antivirus ( e.g. external or windows defender ) and exclude .nuxt from indexing by your IDE

Comment: Ok, this is what i did. There is an option in VS Code called "Watcher Exclude" (defines which files to exclude from file control), so i presumed that it were what i was searching for, then i added the .nuxt folder path (`**/.nuxt/*/**` and `**/.nuxt` in a different try). After disabling Windows Defender i tried to put some new vue files into the pages folder and the first attempts were successful but after a little bit i've experienced the same discrepancies issue and later the `EPERM` errror.

Comment: I even tried the VS Code "Exclude" option (_exclude files or folder from file explorer_) but same results.

Comment: might be caused by this https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/issues/104#issuecomment-335495181

Comment: That post was very illuminating and led me to this `graceful-fs` package. So, to handle file rewriting and honor the Windows "watch" behavior on files, an user created this alternative `fs` node package that should allow to write on files without any issues about permissions (`EPERM`). I found a webpack plugin version of graceful-fs and according to the nuxt's doc i placed the plugin instance call into the `build` block of the `nuxt.config.js`. Unfortunately this new addition didn't work, i got this error `DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on .hooks instead`.